# Getting imported targets through `find_package`?

Tags: cmake

The [CMake manual of Qt 5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) uses `find_package` and says:

> Imported targets are created for each Qt module. Imported target names should be preferred instead of using a variable like `Qt5<Module>_LIBRARIES` in CMake commands such as target_link_libraries.

Is it special for Qt or does `find_package` generate *imported targets* for all libraries? The [documentation of `find_package` in CMake 3.0](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) says:

> When the package is found package-specific information is provided through variables and Imported Targets documented by the package itself.

And the [manual for cmake-packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) says:

> The result of using `find_package` is either a set of IMPORTED targets, or a set of variables corresponding to build-relevant information.

But I did not see another `FindXXX.cmake`-script where the documentation says that a *imported target* is created.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`find_package` is a two-headed beast these days:

> CMake provides direct support for two forms of packages, [Config-file Packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html)
> and [Find-module Packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#find-module-packages)

[Source](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html)

Now, what does that actually mean?

**Find-module packages** are the ones you are probably most familiar with. They execute a script of CMake code (such as [this one](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake)) that does a bunch of calls to functions like [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) and [`find_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html) to figure out where to locate a library.

The big advantage of this approach is that it is extremely generic. As long as there is something on the filesystem, we can find it. The big downside is that it often provides little more information than the physical location of that something. That is, the result of a find-module operation is typically just a bunch of filesystem paths. This means that modelling stuff like transitive dependencies or multiple build configurations is rather difficult.

This becomes especially painful if the thing you are trying to find has *itself* been built with CMake. In that case, you already have a bunch of stuff modeled in your build scripts, which you now need to painstakingly reconstruct for the find script, so that it becomes available to downstream projects.

This is where **config-file packages** shine. Unlike find-modules, the result of running the script is not just a bunch of paths, but it instead creates fully functional CMake targets. To the dependent project it looks like the dependencies have been built as part of that same project.

This allows to transport much more information in a very convenient way. The obvious downside is that config-file scripts are much more complex than find-scripts. Hence you do not want to write them yourself, but have CMake generate them for you. Or rather have the dependency provide a config-file as part of its deployment which you can then simply load with a `find_package` call. And that is exactly what Qt5 does.

This also means, if your own project is a library, consider [generating a config file as part of the build process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages). It's not the most straightforward feature of CMake, but the results are pretty powerful.

Here is a quick comparison of how the two approaches typically look like in CMake code:

*Find-module style*

```
find_package(foo)
target_link_libraries(bar ${FOO_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(bar ${FOO_INCLUDE_DIR})
# [...] potentially lots of other stuff that has to be set manually
```

*Config-file style*

```
find_package(foo)
target_link_libraries(bar foo)
# magic!
```

**tl;dr**: Always prefer config-file packages if the dependency provides them. If not, use a find-script instead.

Comment: So why then, does cmake look for modules first and fallback on configs? It seems like config mode gives way better info, and should be done first. Though, it sucks if the config mode and module mode import targets with different names.  This could create serious problems if you depend on config mode being the only one found, and later a module is added to cmake that doesn't import the target as you expect.

Comment: @johnb003 This is for historical reasons to not break backward-compatibility with existing scripts. You can force CMake into config-style by passing `CONFIG` or `NO_MODULE` to the `find_package` call. In any case, calls should typically not be ambigious. In the vast majority of cases, you will only have one type of script available to be found, so there is no conflict. For those few cases where there is an ambiguity, you should say explicitly which mode you expect `find_package` to operate in.

Comment: Understood, that you can force config mode, but this is awkward. The simple example when this happens is if you distribute a set of 3rd party packages via a relocatable installation path. The problem is you don't want to go start hacking all of the find_package calls of 3rd party libraries to be "CONFIG" mode, it should just work. CMake docs even advocate that mostly you should just use the conical form: `find_package(<package> [major[.minor]] [EXACT] [REQUIRED|QUIET])`

Comment: Some Find-module packages, such as Boost, include multiple libraries. Do Config-file packages account for that? Can a `foo` such as in the `target_link_libraries(bar foo)` example above, resolve to multiple libraries?

Comment: From FindBoost.cmake: `Boost::<C> - Target for specific component dependency (shared or static library); <C> is lower-case`. For example: `Boost::filesystem`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is no "magic" with results of `find_package`: this command just searches appropriate `FindXXX.cmake` script and executes it.

If Find script sets `XXX_LIBRARY` variable, then caller can use this variable.

If Find script creates imported targets, then caller can use these targets.

If Find script *neither sets* `XXX_LIBRARY` variable *nor creates* imported targets ... well, then usage of the script is somehow different.

Documentation for `find_package` describes *usual* usage of Find scripts. But in any case you need to consult documentation about *concrete* script (this documentation is normally contained in the script itself).