# "config-style" cmake find_package unusable in parent scope

Tags: cmake

I have the following structure

```
project_root/
    CMakeLists.txt     (A)
    ext/
        CMakeLists.txt (B)
    apps/
        CMakeLists.txt (C)
```

The setup seems to be the fundamental issue, only when adding this new "config-style" library.

**TL;DR: when `find_package(foo)` in (B) defines `foo::foo` as the library, how can I make `foo::foo` available in the parent scope so that `target_link_libraries(tgt foo)` will work for both (A) and (C)?**

1. List (A) defines my project's options, such as what drivers to compile support for.
2. `add_subdirectory(ext)` takes place, and the needed external libraries are found.  They are a mixture of `add_subdirectory` and `find_package`.  List (B) populates lists for extra include directories, libraries, and compile time definitions, making them available to (A) (and subsequently (C)) with

   ```
   set(MYPROJ_EXTRA_INC_DIRS "${MYPROJ_EXTRA_INC_DIRS}" PARENT_SCOPE)
   set(MYPROJ_EXTRA_LIBS     "${MYPROJ_EXTRA_LIBS}"     PARENT_SCOPE)
   set(MYPROJ_EXTRA_DEFINES  "${MYPROJ_EXTRA_DEFINES}"  PARENT_SCOPE)
   ```
3. List (A) now adds my library, including these extra directories, adding these extra definitions, and ultimately

   ```
   target_link_libraries(${MYPROJ_LIB_NAME} ${MYPROJ_EXTRA_LIBS})
   ```
4. When the applications are requested to be built, `add_subdirectory(apps)` takes place, and list (C) defines a simple macro that creates an executable using the specified dependencies.  The relevant part

   ```
   target_link_libraries(${appName} ${MYPROJ_LIB_NAME} ${MYPROJ_EXTRA_LIBS})
   ```

**This has been working very well for a long time**.  However, I added support for a new library that uses [config-style `find_package`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35840894/3814202) definitions, and I can't figure out how to use it correctly.

Call this new library dependency `foo`.  It ultimately defines a single `foo_LIBRARY` which is `foo::foo`.  My understanding was that I would need to do `target_link_libraries(tgt foo)`, which works in list (A) for my library.  However, it does not work for the applications, and in the macro I have to do `find_package(foo)` again for every executable.

Is there a way to use the existing approach (`list(APPEND MYPROJ_EXTRA_LIBS <something>)`) that does **not** require running `find_package` every time?

I've exhausted every reasonable option, and either get that `-lfoo` is not defined (if I just append `foo` to the list like I thought I should be), or `find_package()` is missing for an IMPORTED or ALIAS target.  AKA since `find_package(foo)` happens in (B), by the time we reach (C) this target is not available.  I tried making an ALIAS, but the error was then something that amounts to ALIAS cannot be created to an IMPORTED library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Results of `find_package` call(both *CONFIG* and *MODULE*) are intended be used in the same directory or below. You are just lucky in that simple propagating of variables into *PARENT_SCOPE* makes results of `find_package` usable by the parent.

> `add_subdirectory(ext)` takes place, and the needed external libraries are found.

Instead of `ext/CMakeLists.txt` included with `add_subdirectory` create CMake file (e.g. `external.cmake`) for being included via `include`. Because `include` command doesn't introduce new variable's scope, its `find_package` calls works for the main `CMakeLists.txt`.

Many existed projects process their dependencies in `include` files.

---

Another approach would be propagating results of `find_package` calls from subdirectory to the parent by creating *INTERFACE* library target which itself uses these results:

```
add_library(MyLibExtra INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(MyLibExtra INTERFACE ${MYPROJ_EXTRA_LIBS})
target_include_directories(MyLibExtra INTERFACE ${MYPROJ_EXTRA_INC_DIRS})
target_compile_definitions(MyLibExtra INTERFACE ${MYPROJ_EXTRA_DEFINES})
```

Comment: I see, that's solid advice -- writing it up right now.  However, I designed the library to be able to build as a child project.  The `MYPROJ_EXTRA_LIBS` and related being necessary for the parent project.  So even if I get it working for my project, once `add_subdirectory(myproj)` goes down in the parent project, this will ultimately still break right?

Comment: Hmm, I have added a way with *INTERFACE* library. Probably, it will helps in the case when your library is actually a subproject. BTW, `set` with *PARENT_SCOPE* propagates a variable only to a *direct* parent. A "grandparent" won't see that variable.

Comment: Ok so I haven't quite gotten everything working, but the interface approach is **definitely** the way to go here.  I've never used this before, but it's really quite wonderful -- thanks!  For those reading this, with my library `myproj` getting built and linking against `myproj-interface` library, everything ripples through.  In the parent project, when I do `target_link_libraries(someTgt myproj)`, since `myproj` links against `myproj-interface`, the parent project doesn't even need to know about the extra libraries going on!